# Wordpress 3.4.2 custom permalinks for Posts, Archives, and Categories only

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

We have a custom WordPress theme running on WordPress 3.4.2 and are running into some problems with our Permalink settings and a particular calendar plugin we're using on our website. Our website is somewhat non-traditional in the sense that all of our Posts are located within a section of the website called /news-events/ (e.g. www.domain.com/news-events/).

Currently, we are using the following custom permalink structure: /news-events/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/ to match the location of our Posts. We have created about 30 websites from this template using this permalink format without any issues.

However, the calendar plugin (The Events Calendar Pro 2.0.10) we're using on this particular site requires the Permalink structure to be /%postname%/. When the permalink structure is set to anything other than /%postname%/, any calendar events pages return 404 pages. Unfortunately, setting our Permalink structure to /%postname%/ is not a viable option for us as it's imperative for us to keep the /news-events/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/.

**The Question:**

Is it possible to set the overall WordPress Permalinks to /%postname%/ while customizing the Permalink structure for Posts, Archives, and Categories to /news-events/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/? Put another way: how can we change the Permalink structure to /news-events/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/ ONLY when a Post, Category, or Archive is being viewed?

---

The following pages provided some useful information, however, it seems we'd need to do the opposite of what's described:
http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks
http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you contacted the developer?

Comment: Yes, we have contacted the developer and they confirmed that the plugin has issues with any other permalink structure other than /%postname%/

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the permalink structure to `%postname%/news-events/%year%/%monthnum%` ?

It may possible allow the plugin to grab the first part of the request (Being postname)